# Applying ACLs to a Dovecot public namespace

Tags: email, access-control-list, imap, dovecot, namespaces

I would like to provide access to some mailing lists via a set of
public, read-only mailboxes in Dovecot.  I have a public namespace
define in my dovecot (dovecot-2.0.9) configuration that looks like
this:

```
namespace {
  type = public
  separator = .
  prefix = news.
  location = maildir:/var/spool/news
  subscriptions = no  
}
```

I would like to make all the mailboxes in this namespace read-only.
I've got the following configuration for the ACL plugin:

```
plugin {
  acl = vfile:/etc/dovecot/acls:cache_secs=300
}
```

After perusing the documentation, it seemed as if I had a mailfolder
`/var/spool/news/.foo.bar` that I could place the following into
`/var/spool/news/.foo.bar/dovecot-acl`:

```
anyone rl
```

But that doesn't have any affect.  I also tried creating a file
`/usr/local/etc/dovecot/acls/news.foo.bar` with the same contents, but
that didn't do anything, either.  I've turned on mail debugging:

```
mail_debug = yes
```

But the log doesn't produce anything that appears to be relevant to
ACL processing.  I'm curious to know if anyone has gotten this to work
correctly and if so if you could provide some configuration examples.

Also, if there's any way to do this that doesn't involve per-mailbox
configuration (.e.g, the ability to apply an ACL to `news.*` or
something), that would be awesome. Getting the documented behavior for
default ACLs working would be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this is an old post, so I imagine you've got this figured out by now. Otherwise, I hope you find the following helpful.

Make sure you've defined a **private** namespace, in addition to the public one. Something along the lines of:

```
namespace {
  type = private
  separator = . # don't mix separators
  prefix =
  #location defaults to mail_location.
  inbox = yes
}
```

At this point `mail_location` is a required parameter, give it a value appropriate for your environment, i.e.:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

The following is also required in `dovecot.conf` (or in one of the additional configs in etc/conf.d) to enable the acl plugin:

```
mail_plugins = acl
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins imap_acl
}
```

If you installed dovecot from source with the default prefix of `/usr/local` --  as would seem to be the case -- then I expect the following is more appropriate for configuring Global ACLs:

```
plugin {
  acl = vfile:/usr/local/etc/dovecot/acls:cache_secs=300
}
```

Restart dovecot and you should be good to go.

You may also find the following documentation useful:

1. http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SharedMailboxes/Public
2. http://wiki2.dovecot.org/ACL

Good luck!